# Reading Json Curl content results in php

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a json output below that am trying to get its contents

```
{"content":"people",
"nextLink":"https://example.com/people?$skip=3",
"value":[

{
"id":"100","displayName":"Room Rainier",
"Addresses":[{"location":"12 orlando street","Spore":8.0}],
"phones":[{"type":"home","number":"10000000000"}],
"personType":{"class":"new","subclass":"Room1"}
},

{
"id":"102","displayName":"Tony Blur",
"Addresses":[{"location":"19 saco street","Spore":4.0}],
"phones":[{"type":"business","number":"1080000000"}],
"personType":{"class":"Other","subclass":"Room2"}
},

{
"id":"103","displayName":"veronica huges",
"Addresses":[{"location":"6 nano street","Spore":7.0}],
"phones":[{"type":"business","number":"111000000"}],
"personType":{"class":"old","subclass":"Room5"}
}]}
```

Below is my working Json Curl in PHP

```
<?php 
session_start();
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 

CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/people",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
//CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
//CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$data", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"authorization: Bearer --my bearer goes here--"
), 
));
$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$res=json_decode($response);
$res1=json_decode($response, true);
$js = json_decode($response, true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($response, true) . '</pre>';
$re = $js['value'];
foreach ($re as $value1) {
  echo $value1['id'];
   echo '<br>';
 echo $value1['Addresses']['location'];
   echo '<br>';

   echo $value1['phones']['type'];
   echo '<br>';
}
if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
//echo $response; 
}
?>
```

**my success**
I was able to get  all values for id `**(echo $value1['id'])**` in for each loops.

**my Problem**

1.) I cannot get values for  Addresses Locations `**(echo $value1['Addresses']['location'])**` and phones Types `**(echo $value1['phones']['type'])**` in for each loop respectively as it shows nothing.

2.) The json file has a next link options hence 
**`"nextLink":"https://example.com/people?$skip=3"`**

how can I display more users/peoples data based on the link. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Addresses and Phones are Arrays so if you want to get the first you can use  index 0 or you can get all with loop in case there is more than 1 address or phone.

```
foreach ($re as $value1) {
    /**
     * To get the first address and phone use index 0
     */
    echo $value1['Addresses'][0]['location'];
    echo $value1['phones'][0]['type'];

    /**
     * Loop to get all addresses and phones
     */
    foreach($value1['Addresses'] as $address) {
        echo $address['location'];
    }

    foreach($value1['phones'] as $phone) {
        echo $phone['type'];
    }
}
```

If there is a next link you should request the nextLink just use curl again with the next link.

It will be easier if you create a function for this and just call the function again with the next link.